# how to use python/matplotlib to plot data with blank line inbetween

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot

I have a single data file that looks like this

```
#X    Y 
1     23.2 
2     24.01
3     67.34
4     68.90
# 

1    7.87 
2    6.90  
3    5.78   
4    7.89
```

Note the gap between the lines.
In my plot I should have two separate lines just as gnuplot would plot it. How to do this with python/matplotlib. I am currently getting one line that joins back.

Here is how I am plotting currently:

```
F=loadtxt('fort.30',comments='#',dtype='float64' )
t=F[:,0]
E=F[:,1]  
plt.plot(t,E)
```

Thanks for the comments and response

Answer (score 3):

Add None's or nans between the parts of your dataset:

```
plt.plot([1,2,None,3,4],[1,0,None,2,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split your `F` array into several subplots whenever the value in the first column is smaller than it was in the line before.

```
breaks = [i for i in range(len(F)) if i > 0 and F[i, 0] < F[i-1, 0]]
borders = [0] + breaks + [len(F)]
subplots = [F[borders[i]:borders[i+1]] for i in range(len(borders)-1)]
```

Now, you can plot the individual subplots.

```
for f in subplots:
    t, E = f[:, 0], f[:, 1]
    plt.plot(t, E)
plt.show()
```

Of course, that's only if the first value of a new subplot will always be lower than the last one of the previous subplot. If you have to rely on the `#` to subdivide the plots, you will probably have to parse the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown any code so far. Your current code might help, based on this people might come up with a working solution for you.

Basically, you have to do the file processing in Python yourself. If `#` is the delimiter between your datasets, then write yourself a function in Python that is reading a file, interpreting line by line. If a line contains 2 numbers separated by whitespace, add the data of that line to the current data set. If a line contains only a `#` (number sign), then start a new data set.

After doing so, you have a clear representation of your data sets (either in Python lists or in numpy arrays) and can worry about plotting those.

Comment: <pre><code>F=loadtxt('fort.30',comments='#',dtype='float64' )
t=F[:,0]
E=F[:,1]  plt.plot(t,E) </pre></code>

Comment: If this is for all of us, then please edit your initial question.